# Full calendar: display multiple months on single view

Tags: fullcalendar, scheduler, fullcalendar-scheduler

I am using Full calendar scheduler, Wanted to display multiple months on single view.

Is there any ideas to implement that without changing the source code?

Answer (score -1):

This issue is still open with fullcalendar team. See

```
https://fullcalendar.io/issues/
```